# How to sort a NSArray with another NSArray?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

```
NSArray A = @[[[@"id":@"3"]], [[@"id":@"4"]] ,[[@"id":@"c"]],[[@"id":@"f"]]];
NSArray idArray = @[@"c", @"3", @"4",@"f"];
```

Just a example I assumed.
How can I sort A by its id with idArray?

That is, I want A to become:

```
NSArray A= @[[[@"id":@"c"]], [[@"id":@"3"]] ,[[@"id":@"4"]],[[@"id":@"f"]]];
```

Now, I want to ask for an algorithm to sort array A to get the desired result.

--***-I get my answer when I search in google:***

```
NSArray *sorter = @[@"B", @"C", @"E"];
NSMutableArray *sortee = [@[
    @[@"B", @"abc"],
    @[@"E", @"pqr"],
    @[@"C", @"xyz"]
] mutableCopy];

[sortee sortUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSString *s1 = [o1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *s2 = [o2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger idx1 = [sorter indexOfObject:s1];
    NSInteger idx2 = [sorter indexOfObject:s2];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
```

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: I have edited my question. Wish you see again

Comment: please check that NSArray format in Xcode it is wrong.
and why you are not using simple NSDictionary for that

Comment: All this doesn't make sense. The "arrays" should be dictionaries, the deep array encapsulation, the sorting output. Please show some effort when asking questions. Working code would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare both array you can use

```
NSArray *array1=@[@"3",@"4",@"c","f"];
NSArray *array2=@[@"c",@"3",@"4","f"];

array1=[array1 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
array2=[array2 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]) {
    NSLog(@"both are same");
}
else{
   NSLog(@"both are differnt");
}
```

or If you want to get common elements from 2 array use

```
NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
[set1 intersectSet:set2]; //this will give you only the obejcts that are in both sets

NSArray* result = [set1 allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better way to make a dictionary for A. And then sorting based on their specific values like IQ, Name etc.

```
NSArray A = @[[[@"id":@"3"]], [[@"id":@"4"]] ,[[@"id":@"c"]],[[@"id":@"f"]]];
NSArray idArray = @[@"c", @"3", @"4",@"f"];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int id = 0;idx<[A count];id++) {
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Name": A[id],@"IQ":idArray[id]};
[array addObject:dict];
}

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"IQ" ascending:NO];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]]
```